# Demora a la hora de mostrar ion-list en ionic v3

Tags: ionic

acabo de realizar mi primer app con ionic, el mismo comprende geolocalización y cálculo de distancias mediante las google apis, de momento funciona, el problema es que se tarda demasiado en renderizar la grilla (ion-list) cuando modifico los (ion-items) dentro de la promesa resultante del método GetDistanceMatrix.

Espero que alguien con más experiencia sepa indicarme que estoy realizando mal.

Este es el código:

```
let me = this;
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(value =>{
let position = value;

  for(let x = 0; x < me.packages.length; x++){
    console.log('Iteration');
    let service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)],
      destinations: [new google.maps.LatLng(me.packages[x].packageOriginLatitude, me.packages[x].packageOriginLongitude)],
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, (response, status) => {
      if (status == 'OK') {

        let json_response = JSON.stringify(response);
        let googleMtr : googleMatrix = JSON.parse(json_response);            
        for(let i = 0; i < googleMtr.rows[0].elements.length; i++){
          me.packages[x].packageDistanceKms = googleMtr.rows[0].elements[i].distance.text;
        }
        console.log('Element updated package: '+x+' distance: '+me.packages[x].packageDistanceKms);
      }
      if (x == me.packages.length -1)
        me.loadfinished = true;

      me.packageCollection = me.packages.slice(0);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Posteo la resolución por si hay algún interesado, el desempeño de la lista mejoró al reorganizar el código y 'envolver' el callback de getDistanceMatrix como una Promise.

```
/*  ------------------------------------- Metodos asincronicos -----------------------------------  */



async getPosition() {
  let position = await this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
  return position;
}

/*  ------------------------------------- Metodos asincronicos -----------------------------------  */

  async calculateDistance(){

    let position = await this.getPosition();
    let service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    let parameters : any;
    for(let i  = 0; i < this.packages.length; i++){
      parameters = {
        origins: [new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)],
        destinations: [new google.maps.LatLng(this.packages[i].packageOriginLatitude, this.packages[i].packageOriginLongitude)],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      };

      let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        service.getDistanceMatrix(parameters , (response, status) => {
        if (status == 'OK') {
          let json_response = JSON.stringify(response);
          let googleMtr : googleMatrix = JSON.parse(json_response);
          let text = '';
          for(let i = 0; i < googleMtr.rows[0].elements.length; i++)
            text = googleMtr.rows[0].elements[i].distance.text;
          resolve(text);
        }
        });
      });

      prom.then(data => {
        this.packages[i].packageDistanceKms = data;
      });

    }
    this.loadfinished = true;

  }
```